# SimpleXMLElement and Warning: Illegal offset type

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

Warning: Illegal offset type

i have this var from an xml output

```
var_dump($key);
```

its give me

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (1) { [0]=> string(5) "Cairo" }
```

now i want make "Cairo" as a key to get its value like

```
$lang[] = array('Cairo' => "Cairo city");
```

the error appear when do this

```
echo $lang[$key];
```

and its give me the `"Warning: Illegal offset type" because of the key is SimpleXMLElement`
how i can make it normal var?

Comment: How your question looks now, Try to format the question you are not a newbie to make this mistake

Comment: Is this `$lang[] = array('Cairo' = "Cairo city");` on purpose? Should be `$lang[] = array('Cairo' => "Cairo city");` AFAICT. (Or `$lang[] = array('Cairo', "Cairo city");` depending on what you're trying to do.)

Comment: => to replace Cairo by its value "Cairo city"

Comment: Can you try with this `$key=(string)$key; echo $lang[$key];`

Comment: @ Shakti Singh you r the best

Answer (score 9):

Cast it to a string with `(string)$key`.